# Interior of a set property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator{\int}{int}$Let $A,B$ be subspaces of the metric space $X$. If $A \subseteq B$ then $\int A \subseteq \int B$.

Proof:

Let $x \in\int A$. Since $x$ is interior to the subspace $A$, there exists a radius $r>0$ so that $B(x,r) \subseteq A$. Because $A \subseteq B$, it must be the case that $B(x,r) \subseteq B$ and so $x$ is interior to $B$, in other words, $\int A \subseteq \int B$.

I would very much love feedback on this proof.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. The only thing I would emphasize is $B(x,r)\subseteq A\subseteq B$ so $B(x,r)\subseteq B$. (Note: what you have is definitely correct, but depending on who the grader is determines the level of details they expect.)

Comment: Is it meant to be general topology or just metric spaces?  Seems a bit excessive to tag `general-topology` here.

Comment: @Clayton thank you very much. Out of curiosity, using this and the fact than an open ball is an open set, I can then conclude that for a subspace Y of X, $int(intY) = intY$, am I correct?

Comment: @topologicalmagician: Correct

Answer (score 1):

Good job!

Anyway observe that,  $\text{Int}A \subseteq A \subseteq B$. So $\text{Int}A$ is an open set contained in $B$. But $\text{Int}B$ is the largest open set contained in $B$, so we must have $\text{Int}A \subseteq \text{Int}B$